# Azure DevOps Burndown Chart - Field Completed not being updated

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a burndown chart that shows the remaining work perfectly but the field 'Completed' is not being updated, it is always showing 0%, and I have tasks 'Done' and the field 'Completed Work' populated by the developers. Does anyone know how the 'Completed' field is calculated? Or have an idea of why this field is not changing for me?

Comment: Which TFS process template are you using? Agile or CMMI?